# Hibernate Fetch Profile not working for nested level entites (Three Levels)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have four entities like start , first, second, third .

**start** having One to Many with **first** (Unidirectional)
**first** having One to Many with **second** (Unidirectional)
**second** having One to Many with **third** (Unidirectional)

#### Fetch profiles are defined in start class. It will be enabled at runtime using session.enableFetchProfile() method

#### If i fetch start entity i want to fetch all entities. How to do it with fetch profile concept. Currently it fetch only two levels.

Start Entity

```
     @Entity
    @FetchProfiles({
        @FetchProfile(name="Start_First_Second_Third_FP",fetchOverrides={
                @FetchOverride(entity=Start.class,association="list_first",mode=FetchMode.JOIN),
                @FetchOverride(entity=First.class,association="list_second",mode=FetchMode.JOIN),
                @FetchOverride(entity=Second.class,association="list_third",mode=FetchMode.JOIN)
        })
    })
    public class Start {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int start_id;
        
        private String name;
    
        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="start_id")
        private Set<First> list_first = new HashSet<First>();
// Getter and Setter here
}
```

First Entity

```
@Entity
public class First{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int first_id;
    
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="first_id")
    private Set<Second> list_second = new HashSet<Second>();
// Setter and Getter 
}
```

Second Entity

```
@Entity
public class Second{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int second_id;
    
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="second_id")
    private Set<Third> list_third = new HashSet<Third>();
// Setter and Getters
}
```

Third Entity

```
@Entity
public class Third{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int third_id;
    
    private String name;

    public int getThird_id() {
        return third_id;
    }
// Setters and Getters
}
```

Retrieving Start Entity

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();          
Transaction td = session.beginTransaction();

session.enableFetchProfile("Start_First_Second_Third_FP"); // Enabled Fetch Profile

System.out.println("Session Fetch Profile is "+session.isFetchProfileEnabled("Start_First_Second_Third_FP")); // It prints True

List<Object> objects = session.createCriteria(Start.class).list();
```

Hibernate Generated Query is :

```
select
        this_.start_id as start_id1_31_2_,
        this_.name as name2_31_2_,
        list_first2_.start_id as start_id3_2_4_,
        list_first2_.first_id as first_id1_2_4_,
        list_first2_.first_id as first_id1_2_0_,
        list_first2_.name as name2_2_0_,
        list_secon3_.first_id as first_id3_29_5_,
        list_secon3_.second_id as second_i1_29_5_,
        list_secon3_.second_id as second_i1_29_1_,
        list_secon3_.name as name2_29_1_ 
    from
        Start this_ 
    left outer join
        First list_first2_ 
            on this_.start_id=list_first2_.start_id 
    left outer join
        Second list_secon3_ 
            on list_first2_.first_id=list_secon3_.first_id
```

Here I have enabled all FetchProfiles but hibernate queries Only three tables like this

**start --> First --> Second 


But i want Four tables joining 


start --> First --> Second --> Third**

Please provide solution i have critical situation.